# ASP.NET Core controller usefull errormessage return

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, asp.net-core

My application is an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API.

```
[HttpGet("{someData:MinLength(5):MaxLength(5)}")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomeData(string someData)
{
    return this.Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Data is: " + someData));
}
```

So when i pass a parameter with the `length 6`, the controller returns the `Response Code 404` and the `Response body no content` because the parameter doesnt have the `length 5`.

This information is pretty useless for me, is there a way to return a more usefull error message?

I know i could just hardcode the error message in every controller like that:

```
[HttpGet("{someData}")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomeData(string someData)
{
      if (someData.Length != 5)
      {
          return this.StatusCode(404, JsonConvert.SerializeObject("The data has to be 5 digits long."));
      }
    return this.Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Data is: " + someData));
}
```

The problem about this is, I have many controllers in my application and I dont want to validate the parameters everytime.

Is there a way the controller returns a more usefull Responsebody by itself? Or do I really have to add a validation method in each controller and forget about the `[HttpGet]` parameters and its error return?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route constraints are used to restrict which requested paths make it to a given action / route destination. They're not meant to perform model validation - that's done later and through a separate mechanism. If the request doesn't conform to your route constraints, it simply won't match that route. If it doesn't match any route, you'll get a 404.

As you noted in your own answer, this is covered in the routing docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-template-reference

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found an answer:

It's not possible to get better error messages.

> Warning
>
> Avoid using constraints for input validation, because doing so means
>   that invalid input will result in a 404 (Not Found) instead of a 400
>   with an appropriate error message. Route constraints should be used to
>   disambiguate between similar routes, not to validate the inputs for a
>   particular route.

found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-template-reference)